# query metrics on tag value with regex in datadog

Tags: monitoring, datadog

I want to filter metrics on tag value with a regex. I can do it in Prometheus but I could not find an equivalent way in Datadog.

For example, to select the following metric whose `status` tag value starts with `2`, I can use the query `http.server.requests.count{status=~"^2..$"}`

I have the same metric with the same tags in Datadog too, but couldn't find a way to have the same query.

Comment: At the moment, this does not seem supported. The best workaround would be to use the advanced query and set something like: `http.server.requests.count{status=200}+http.server.requests.count{status=201}+...`

Comment: I think it is not a good option to list all possible combinations.

since there isn't a good solution for it, I added another dimension to group HttpStatus like 2xx, 5xx on the application level.

Comment: Does `status:[200 TO 299]` work?

Comment: could you please point to any documentation about the [x To y] syntax?

Comment: `status:[200 TO 299]` would only work in the APM and Log explorer but not for metrics

Comment: @Muatik there it is: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/search_syntax/#numerical-values

Answer (score 4):

Metrics queries now support wildcards.

Example 1: Getting all the requests with a status tag starting with `2`:
`http.server.requests.count{status:2*}`

Example 1: Getting all the requests with a service tag ending with `mongo`:
`http.server.requests.count{service:*mongo}`

Example 3 (advanced): Getting all the requests with a service tag starting with `blob` and ending with `postgres`:
`http.server.requests.count{service:blob*,service:*postgres}`
*(this will match `service:blob-foo-postgres` and `service:blob_bar_postgres` but not `service:my_name_postgres`)*

Comment: Best I can tell, there is still no way to filter on text in the middle. Its either a begins with or ends with filter ☹️

Comment: do you really need to TAG the everything on datadog?